# what is this error? "module' object has no attribute 'Fila'"

Tags: python

My python code is giving this error as I run. It may be due to circular imports, but I can't find the solution. I've tried changing the name of the file and importing fila_module in **init** of simulador but it didn't work

There is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/simulador.py", line 9, in <module>
    import fila_module
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/fila_module.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Eventos
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/Eventos.py", line 12, in <module>
    import simulador
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/simulador.py", line 68, in <module>
    s = Simulador(480)
  File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/simulador.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.client_queue = fila_module.Fila(self,2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Fila'
```

simulador.py

```
import fila_module
import lista
import Eventos


class Simulador:

    def insereEvento(self,event):
        self.event_list.insert_event(event)

    #Construtor
    def __init__(self, tempo_simulacao):
        self.tempo_simulacao = tempo_simulacao
        #Médias das distribuições de chegadas e de atendimento no serviço
        self.media_cheg = 1
        self.media_serv = 1.5
        #Número de clientes que vão ser atendidos
        self.n_clientes = 100

        #Relógio de simulação - variável que contém o valor do tempo em cada instante
        self.instant = 0        #valor inicial a zero       

        #Serviço - pode haver mais do que um num simulador
        self.client_queue = fila_module.Fila(self,2)
        self.loja_queue = fila_module.Fila(self,1)
        #Lista de eventos - onde ficam registados todos os eventos que vão ocorrer na simulação
        #Cada simulador só tem uma
        self.event_list = lista.Lista(self)

        #Agendamento da primeira chegada
        #Se não for feito, o simulador não tem eventos para simular
        self.insereEvento(Eventos.Chegada(self.instant, self))

#Cria um simulador e
s = Simulador(480)
#põe-o em marcha
s.executa()
```

fila_module.py

```
import Eventos

class Fila:
    """Classe que representa um serviço com uma fila de espera associada"""


    # Construtor
    def __init__(self, sim, n_atendedores):
        self.fila=[]                #Fila de espera do serviço
        self.simulator = sim            #Referência para o simulador a que pertence o serviço
        self.estado = 0             #Variável que regista o estado do serviço: 0 - livre; 1 - ocupado
        self.temp_last = sim.instant        #Tempo que passou desde o último evento. Neste caso 0, porque a simulação ainda não começou.
        self.atendidos = 0          #Número de clientes atendidos até ao momento
        self.soma_temp_esp = 0
        self.soma_temp_serv = 0
        self.n_atendedores = n_atendedores
        self.atendidos_no_momento = 0

    def insereClient(self,client):
        """Método que insere cliente (client) no serviço"""
        if(self.estado < n_atendedores):    #Se serviço livre,
            self.atendidos_no_momento += 1
            if self.atendidos_no_momento == n_atendedores:
                self.estado = 1 #fica ocupado e
            #agenda saída do cliente c para daqui a self.simulator.media_serv instantes
            self.simulator.insereEvento(Eventos.Saida(self.simulator.instant + self.simulator.media_serv,self.simulator))
        else:
            self.fila.append(client) #Se serviço ocupado, o cliente vai para a fila de espera


    def removeClient(self):
        """Método que remove cliente do serviço"""
        self.atendidos = self.atendidos+1 #Regista que acabou de atender + 1 cliente
        if(self.fila==[]):  #Se a fila está vazia,
            self.estado = 0 # liberta o serviço
            self.atendidos_no_momento -= 1
            return None
        else: #Se não,
            #vai buscar próximo cliente à fila de espera e
            cliente = self.fila.pop(0)
            #agenda a sua saida para daqui a self.simulator.media_serv instantes
            self.simulator.insereEvento(Eventos.Saida(self.simulator.instant + self.simulator.media_serv,self.simulator))
            return cliente
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a *circular dependency*. `Eventos` is importing `simulador` which imports `fila_module` which imports `Eventos`. You can see this in the traceback:

```
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/simulador.py", line 9, in <module>
    import fila_module
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/fila_module.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Eventos
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/Eventos.py", line 12, in <module>
    import simulador
File "/Users/miff/Desktop/SCC/simulador.py", line 68, in <module>
```

Python adds names to a module as the module is executed; when the `import Eventos` line in `file_module` runs, the `class Fila` line has not yet been run.

Either avoid creating a circular dependency here (are you *sure* `Eventos` needs to import `simulador` when `simumlador` imports `Eventos`), or move the `import Eventos` to *below* the `class Fila` block.